# Java data mining file I/O program

Tags: java, file, file-io, multidimensional-array, split

I have a programming assignment where I have to 'massage some data' which I'm using from here:
https://data.undp.org/dataset/Table-12-Innovation-and-technology/jixu-gnyy
I want to turn this data (to the exception of a few columns) into a multi-dimensional array so that I can then play around with some data.
My plan is to read the text file into a string, then split according to \n (new lines) to create the rows then according to spaces to create the columns. My problem is the following:
If I split on space the second time it will split at the wrong places because of potential spaces between countries who have more than a word (United Kingdom for example). Does anyone have any way around this?

Comment: Where is the text file you plan to read? You've provided a URL with a bunch of html. Will you be parsing that?

Comment: Yes, the text file I plan to read is under my java file

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why don't you export the data in a CSV format? Then you can split the data using a separator like coma or semicolon (Tipically a semicolon). After that, you can identify each token with no worries!

Comment: Do I need to manually split the data with a coma/semicolon ? 
I try copy paste the data in CSV format to my text editor and all the information is each 'box' is split by line

Comment: Then use the line as a field separator instead of space.